# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

Tags: python, api, amazon-s3

I'm working to in a project and the goal is to pull report from amazon S3. Currently I'm trying to access to an S3 location to check my available bucket list.

Im working in python, I've set all my credentials in the prompt : aws configure.

In my python file when i'm try the code to list all my bucket :

```py
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print (bucket.name)
```

I'm getting this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\bakpovo\testAmazon.py", line 3, in 
>           for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
>         File "C:\Users\bakpovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\collection.py", line 83, in **iter**
>           for page in self.pages():
>         File "C:\Users\bakpovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\collection.py", line 161, in pages
>           pages = [getattr(client, self._py_operation_name)(**params)]
>         File "C:\Users\bakpovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 276, in _api_call
>           return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\bakpovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 586, in _make_api_call
>           raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
>       botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

Does someone have any idea of what happened? Are my creadentials not good?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Are you able to read/list the buckets with the `aws s3` terminal/shell command? 2. After running `aws configure` do you have a valid shared credentials file `~/.aws/credentials`? 3. Ref https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials do you have anything that would prevent boto3 from using the shared credentials file (e.g. environment variables set)?

Comment: did you create your credentials as the `default` profile? If you have multiple s3 accounts/ profiles it can be useful to setup named profiles and then create a session: 
```session = boto3.Session(profile_name=<NAME HERE>) 
    s3 = session.resource("s3")```

Comment: Hello @Tom, Thanks for replying. I have already use the 'aws s3 ls s3' in my terminal for the listing and I have the same error. Yes I've my credentials file valid.I don't think I've some environments variables. I just have an S3 location and the secret and access key id

Comment: Hello @Alex, thanks for your answer... I dont create my credentials as default, i've just configure with the acces key id and the secret access key.                                                                             
My s3 location look like this : **s3://aps-external-xxxx/aps-downloadxxx-xxx-43f7ee306fd2/**

Comment: If `aws s3 ls s3` doesn't work with the same error then your credentials are not set up correctly.

Comment: Okay, i'm going to recheck this

Comment: I would check you `~/.aws` directory and look in your credentials file. If everything looks correct in there, then maybe go look at your IAM user and see if you have access to all the buckets in your account.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks you all for your answer. I solve my problem.
I have just add to my shell syntax my s3 location like this :

```
aws s3 ls s3://aps-external-xxxx/aps-downloadxxx-xxx-e306fd2/
```

And it's work.